# Invalid date in HttpCookie.parse; What should be the behavior?

Tags: datetime, java, specifications

Today I changed the java I have been using on my desktop from the Oracle JDK 1.7 to the OpenJDK 1.7.

So I went from

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

to

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I then ran the unit tests for one of my projects and what has been running successfully before now failed. 
The failing test in question did something like this:

```
List<HttpCookie> cookies = 
        HttpCookie.parse("FOO=BAR; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:10 GMT");
HttpCookie cookie = cookies.get(0);
```

and then an assertion using the value from

```
cookie.getMaxAge();
```

The problem I found is that suddenly the cookie.getMaxAge() always returned a 0 instead of the expected 'big' value.

It turns out that I ask an invalid question: 01-Jan-2020 is a Wednesday, not a Thursday.
I fixed this error in my unit test (so now I ask for "Wed, 01-Jan-2020" and this now works).

For me the question remains: What 'should' be the behavior in case of 'not so good input'?

Both behaviors I see here have some validation.

Apparently:

- Oracle: The date can be parsed so we return the value. The 'day of the week' is just a 'hint'.
- OpenJDK: This date cannot exist as it was specified so we return a 0

Is there a specification on this point?

Comment: "*from the Oracle JDK 1.7 to the OpenJDK 1.7*"? OpenJDK is the JDK that Oracle develops -- source, I'm pushing my changes to hg.openjdk.java.net and I'm working for Oracle :-)

Comment: Yes I understand the confusion. With the Oracle one I mean the one you can download here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. What is the 'right' name for that one?

Comment: I would refer to that as OpenJDK.

Comment: I wouldn't. To avoid further confusion I've added the version info for both.

Comment: If 1.7.0_25 is accepting a day name which is not correct for the given date then it appears to me that 1.7.0_25 has a bug, which has apparently been corrected in 1.7.0_65. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) we see that the string must be a set-cookie ([Netscape proposal](https://web.archive.org/web/20080520061150/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html?)) or set-cookie2 ([RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)). Your string is following the Netscape proposal.

From the Netscape proposal:

> The date string is formatted as:

```
Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT
```

> 

This is based on RFC 822, RFC 850, RFC 1036, and RFC 1123, with the variations that the only legal time zone is GMT and the separators between the elements of the date must be dashes.

From [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822):

> 5.2. SEMANTICS
>
> If included, day-of-week must be the day implied by the date specification.

So your string is not a set-cookie string.

The parse method should throw an IllegalArgumentException if:

> header string violates the cookie specification's syntax, or the cookie name contains illegal characters, or the cookie name is one of the tokens reserved for use by the cookie protocol

The day-of-week error is a semantic violation of the specification and not a syntactic one, so no exception has to be raised.

In conclusion, the behavior of the parse method encountering a date with a wrong day-of-week is not defined. The specification should either impose to raise an IllegalArgumentException, either impose to ignore the problem as the day-of-week is an optional redundant information.